# splitting text based on word match with python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string and I want to split it based on word match. How can I do that?
Here is my incomplete attempt

```
text_ = "Sky is beautiful today" 
test = "beautiful"

if test in text_:
    #Here the logic
    print(text_.split(test))
```

The above mentioned code does not work, becasue it removes the matched word

Expected output : `["Sky is","beautiful", "today"]`

Comment: Is it mandatory that you split it by the split function only, or  we are allowed to use other methods too?

Comment: any thing which works. thats what came to my mind that why

Comment: No It does not. The answers are below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression operations are your friend!

A better way is to use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split). This way you only need 1 line.

**Note that the pattern (test) must be a string inside a parenthesis in order to include the word in the output.**

```
text_ = "Sky is beautiful today" 
test = "(beautiful)"

print(re.split(test, text_))
```

Output: `['Sky is ', 'beautiful', ' today']`

Comment: why did you add `()` before the word ? that was not in original word

Comment: The `()` is so the word is in the capture group. without the `()` the word beatiful would not appear in the output as you wanted.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. I changed my source code. I did not understand why it is important though

Comment: In this way is it possible to split checking two words ?

Comment: yes! You can use the regex OR `|` . 
In this case I am spliting by `beautiful`and `my`. 
`test = "(beautiful|my)"`

Answer (score 1):

Well here is an approach I tried, quite a naive one but, works nonetheless for the above case.

```py
text_ = "Sky is beautiful today" 
test = "beautiful"
s = ""
res = []
if test in text_:
  for word in text_.split(" "):
    if word == test:
      res.append(s)
      res.append(test)
      s = ""
    else:
      s += word + " "
  res.append(s)
print(res)
```

There will probably be more efficient methods too for sure.

The output :-

```
['Sky is ', 'beautiful', 'today ']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this and make use of list slicing

Code

```
text = "Sky is beautiful today" 
element = "beautiful"

#Split string into list elements by the occurrence of a " "
words = text.split(" ")
index = words.index(element) #Grab index of specified "word"

preElement = " ".join(words[:index])      #Grab elements before the "word"
postElement = " ".join(words[index+1:])   #Grab elements after the "word"

#Combination, but only works for first occurrence of the "word"
output = [preElement,element,postElement]
print(output)
```

Output

```
['Sky is', 'beautiful', 'today']
```

Comment: No problem, but it would need some adjustments to work with multiple occurrences of the word you're looking for